# Row duplicate every page reload

Tags: php, header, return

I making a simple comment system. When I reload the page the comment which was first inserted is duplicated. Should I use header to redirect with request_uri? I did that and it became a header loop.
Thanks in advance

```
public function comment($username, $comment, $code)
        {
            if(!empty($username) && !empty($comment) && !empty($code))
            {
                $date =date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                if($insert = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO reviews (username, comment, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))
                {
                    $insert->bind_param('sss', $username, $comment, $date);
                    $insert->execute();
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "iets gaat mis met inserten";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "missing fields";
            }
        }
```

```
public function retrieve()
                {
                    if($retrieve = $this->db->query("SELECT username, comment, time FROM reviews ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 5"))
                    {
                            while($row = $retrieve->fetch_assoc())
                            {
                                $output .= '<div class="comment">';
                                $output .= '<div class="name">'.$row['username'].'</div>';
                                $output .= '<div class="date">Added at '.date('H:i \o\n d M Y',strtotime($row['time'])).'"></div>';
                                $output .= '<p>'.$row['comment'].'</p>';
                                $output .= '</div>';
                            }
                            return $output;

                    }

                }
```

```
<?php
$reizen= new reizen;
echo $reizen->retrieve();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<?php
$output = '';
$output .= '<div id="contactform">';
$output .= '<form name="form" id="form" action="index.php?page=review" method="post">';
$output .= '<label>Name:</label>';
$output .= '<input type="text" name="username" />';
$output .= '<label>comment</label>';
$output .= '<textarea name="comment" rows="20" cols="20"></textarea>';
$output .= '<label><img src="captcha.php"></label>';
$output .= '<input type="text" name="code">';
$output .= '<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Send message" />';
$output .= '</form>';
$output .= '</body>';
$output .= '</div>';
$output .= '</html>';
echo $output;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $comment = $_POST['comment'];
  $code = $_POST['code'];
  $reizen->comment($username, $comment, $code);
}
?>
```

Comment: what are you doing with your output?  it sounds like a front end issue to me....

Comment: Does this happen when you reload the page immediately after you insert a comment, or whenever you reload the page?

Comment: whenever I reload the page

Comment: what calls the comment function ?

Comment: you are calling echo $reizen->retrieve(); before adding the new comment so it wonnt show on that current page unless refresh.. MOVE you if(isset($_POST['submit'])) function into top of page.

Answer (score -1):

can you give us hint on how u show $input ?

*also by dublication you mean html duplication or that the form still contain same comment ?
cause if so you can add attr autocomplete="false" to you inputs that submit comments to avoid that.*

since your database is duplicating also. then please show us you form workflow. cuz some where you are calling comment function twice..

a good idea is to put uniqure key on both username,post_id,comment so that a user cannot say exact same comment on same post twice. according to you current situation, this uniqure key will fire error when ever ur code try to resubmit the same comment twice, and u will be able to id when that happens.

---

for debuging

---

-do the unique key trick to also aid u fire error when problem occur.

-u are calling comment() function at end of page.. and the retrive functinon `BEFORE` IT

so what u do is you load all old comments then add that comment (it will not show unless u refresh) to fix that move ur `if($_POST['submit'])` BEFORE calling all comments from database

Comment: I've edited, the rows are also duplicated in the database itself

Comment: then its ur insert is the problem.. please show the hole code so we can provide more help